# Moving context of image JavaFX

Tags: image, javafx, mouseevent

I want to create program to zoom and displacement a context of photo. Something like in Google Maps  - when I clicked on map and move mouse the content of map is changing. I want the same result in my program. Zoom works good  for me. How can I solve that? For now I have a program to move all image not only context of this...
Thanks for helps!

Comment: What is the "context of photo"? Also you cannot move a part of a node: You'll need to move the whole `ImageView`. Furthermore panning is implemented in `ScrollPane`...

Comment: Thanks you for your prompt. I solved this using scrollPane and function setPannable(true)...It was so simple...